# TabNetRegressor doesn't work. The loss is always zero

Tags: python, pytorch

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATvVp.png)
load the dataset about diabetes. When I training TabNetRegressor, it's loss always be zero. But the regrossor can predict the samples, and the prediction is different from true labels.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c11cq.png)

Wish somebody can give a help.

Comment: post the code and not the pictures of code.
Users need to be able to replicate the problem quickly, 
which text allows for (and pictures do not).
[how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)